# C++ strict aliasing rules and pointers to members

Tags: c++, strict-aliasing, member-pointers

The following code yields warning in G++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

template <typename T, typename P, typename Q>
Q T::*pointer_to(P T::*p, Q P::*q)
{
   typedef Q T::* output_ptr;
// warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
   size_t tmp = reinterpret_cast<const size_t&>(p) + reinterpret_cast<const size_t&>(q);
   return reinterpret_cast<const output_ptr&>(tmp);
}

struct A { int x; };
struct B { A a; };

int main()
{
   B b = B();
   b.*pointer_to(&B::a, &A::x) = 1;
   std::cout << b.a.x << std::endl;
}
```

It works properly anyway, but that makes me worry.

What is your opinion, are these "sub-member" pointers susceptible to extra strict aliasing issues than plain member pointers?

Comment: THAT's what's making you worry?  You're making a lot of assumptions of how your compiler has implemented pointer-to-member, and using it to create your own pointer-to-member which points to a sub-member.  The whole thing seems sort of risky and non-portable.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Definitely I understand that the method itself might be non-portable, won't interop properly with virtual bases (though, casting to size_t should then fail), and is everything that is not recommended to be used in C++ programming =)

Comment: The reason why I tried it is rather theoretical. Pointer to member of a plain (actually, POD) class by fact *is* an compile-time constant offset. Pointer to member can point to any member of given type. Offset to any member of a member class has also a fixed offset from class beginning. Imagine then that we need a functional object that modifies that deeply digged member? Or, a item of a member that is a C-array. Language rules disable you from referencing that member directly, so several binds will be required.

Comment: Anyway, I'm still wondering, whether that dirty hack has any additional contradictions against C++ standard besides doing reinterpret_cast-s and relying on G++ internal pointer to member representation.

Ok, you might say: there's no use reasoning about anything that started from doing a banned reinterpret_cast. Still, it looks like that calculated value has so much in common with a plain member pointer that it should have no additional side effect compared with it.

Comment: I don't recommend anyone to practice such diguisting hacking, and I think that I will eventually stick to that solution with binds (I guess it should optimize to the same constant integral offset).
Though it looked so tempting to have a lightweight pointer to member of a member of a member etc. =)

Comment: Interesting: it turned out that bind(&A::x, bind(&B::a, bind(&C::b, _1))) breaks compiler before gcc 4.8.3. Thus I have to use the above hack to overcome this problem until the next Qt release -)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend against doing it this way.

You stated in your comments that you tried using a nested `std::bind`, but there's an issue with the compiler version you're using.  Rather than resort to the hack, I would roll my own repeated pointer to member class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>


template<typename Ptr1, typename... Rest>
class pointer_to_sub;

template<typename ObjType, typename Class>
class pointer_to_sub<ObjType Class::* >
{
  typedef ObjType Class::* ptr_type;

public:
  typedef ObjType value_type;
  typedef Class input_type;
  pointer_to_sub(ptr_type input)  : ptr(input)
  {

  }

  value_type& operator()(input_type& from) const
  {
    return from.*ptr;
  }

  value_type const& operator()(input_type const& from) const
  {
    return from.*ptr;
  }

  value_type& operator()(input_type* from) const
  {
    return from->*ptr;
  }

  value_type const& operator()(input_type const* from) const
  {
    return from->*ptr;
  }



  private:

  ptr_type ptr;
};


template<typename ObjType, typename Class, typename... Rest >
class pointer_to_sub<ObjType Class::*, Rest...> : private pointer_to_sub<Rest...>
{
  typedef ObjType Class::* ptr_type;
  typedef pointer_to_sub<Rest...> base_type;
public:
  typedef typename base_type::value_type value_type;
  typedef Class input_type;

  pointer_to_sub(ptr_type input, Rest... args) : base_type(args...), ptr(input)
  {

  } 

  value_type& operator()(input_type& from) const
  {
    return base_type::operator()(from.*ptr);
  }

  value_type const& operator()(input_type const& from) const
  {
    return base_type::operator()(from.*ptr);
  }


  value_type& operator()(input_type* from) const
  {
    return base_type::operator()(from->*ptr);
  }

  value_type const& operator()(input_type const* from) const
  {
    return base_type::operator()(from->*ptr);
  } 
private:
  ptr_type ptr;
};

template<typename T, typename... Args>
pointer_to_sub<T, Args...> make_pointer_to_sub(T t1, Args... args)
{
  return pointer_to_sub<T, Args...>(t1, args...);
}
```

The above basically provides a `make_pointer_to_sub` which takes a list of member object pointers.  It accepts as its input a reference or a pointer that's convertible to the first type, and then dereferences each of the pointers in turn.  It could be improved to accept `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`, but that's for later.  You use it as seen below.

```
struct A { int x; double y;};
struct B { A a; };

int main()
{
  auto ptr = make_pointer_to_sub(&B::a, &A::x);


   B b = B();
   ptr(b) = 1;
   // b.*pointer_to(&B::a, &A::x) = 1;

   std::cout << b.a.x << std::endl;
   ptr(&b) = 2;
   std::cout << b.a.x << std::endl;

}
```

If you needed to, this could be assigned to a `std::function` with the appropriate arguments.